# some View as an input parameter of a method/initializator

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

Could someone explain how `some View` should be used?

Am I right that a typecast to a wanted type is only a proper algorithm to feed a created variable into another method/initializator?
In the code below only force-cast helped me to create a `TupleView`.

```
let shadowRectangle: some View = self.shadowRectangle(
                width: w,
                heightTop: heightTop
            )
            return AnyView(
                ZStack<TupleView<(Rectangle, Path)>>.init(content: { () -> TupleView<(Rectangle, Path)> in
                    return TupleView<(Rectangle, Path)>.init((shadowRectangle as! Rectangle,
                    simplePathView as! Path))
                })
```

It looks strange that a lot of methods of `View` return `some View`. I should cast it each time when I want to use it outside of the current scope. For example, `.offset()` method returns `some View`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the below the same of that provided, pardon, *nightmare*?

```
var simplePathView: some View {
    // path to be returned here
}

func shadowRectangle(width: CGFloat, heightTop: CGFloat) -> some View {
    // rect to be returned here
}

func foo() -> some View {
    ZStack {
        self.shadowRectangle(width: w, heightTop: heightTop)
        simplePathView
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wrote types explicitly. It doesn't actually matter. But you are right. This is near the same. The question is not about explicit types. The question is about `some protocol` type usage.

Comment: `some` gives possibility to return `any` implementer of protocol, as above, and that will be accepted by type checking.

Comment: We can't use this variable without type casting for my custom method. Or not?

Comment: If you specify *explicit* type in generics then you must provide *explicit* type, but *some* gives possibility do not provide *explicit* type as in my snapshot, so `ZStack` is *a container of some views*, instead of *a container of only Rectangle and Path*

Answer (score 0):

`var x: some AnyProtocol` tells you one thing in swift, nothing else:

> The value of `x` is an exact type (and that can never change), and that certain type conforms to `AnyProtocol`.

It basically hides from you the exact return type, and only lets you know that said type conforms to a protocol, so you can call said protocol's methods on it.

To be back to your example, you are right, if you want the return value to be exactly `ZStack<TupleView<(Rectangle, Path)>>`, you need to cast `some View`-s to `Rectangle` or `Path`. But generally you should not need anything like this, because you lose the purpose of the `some` keyword: to hide the exact type of the views. If you want exact types, then you shouldn't have hidden them by using the `some` keyword in the first place. If you use exact types, the compiler will again be able to infer the generic types, and no casting is needed.

So, I would do this here:

```
let simplePathView: Path = yourPathCreatingFunc()
let shadowRectangle: Rectangle = self.shadowRectangle(width: w, heightTop: heightTop)
return AnyView(ZStack {
    TupleView((simplePathView, shadowRectangle))
})
```

I see many people carelessly use `some View`, as they think it helps them because they don't have to think about return types or variable types, they just write `some View` everywhere. This is a case where it goes wrong, because of the colliding with the true meaning of `some` (as discussed above).

So this question is more of a *why do you need this*, rather than whether you are right or wrong syntactically.